# How to render flat shading just like LookDev in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm making graphics for a tile based game that has 2.5D look. I am making most assets in blender, and everything works out great, except for the walls, that have to have seamless tiling.

I am using a 4x4 wall layout as pictured below to do the tiling, but I can't figure out how to achieve a flat look, where object's geometry does not affect lights.

LookDev shows exactly what I need, but when I render it out with shadows and AO disabled, nearby geometry still affects the shading, and I get darker spots where I want them to be purely flat. Basically I want lighting to show up only according to how face normals are positioned.

Here is the illustration of what I want (left is done in vector graphics software), and what I get (right is Blender). Red marks show problematic spots.

I suspect I need to play around with shading to get this done. Any rendering engine will do, but I would prefer a solution with Cycles, and I must be able to have Freestyle outline.

Workbench does achieve a similar look, but in there the outline is white, and shading looks a little weird and unnatural.

[image: Problem illustrated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.

1. There should only be sun as a light source, no other lights
2. In Object Properties -> Ray Visibility, only Camera should be checked

This produces something that looks a bit more bland than LookDev, but it tiles perfectly.